# Display Additional Form on Update - RadGrid

Tags: popup, telerik, window, radgrid

I'm using a RadGrid for changing record status's. Users have the ability to select a status from a dropdown and update that record with that status. Depending on the status chosen, when the user clicks update I want to popup an additional form so the user can fill out more data required for the update. I'm not sure the best way to go about implementing this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the RadWindow like a modal and pop it up to the user via client-side JavaScript.  We use RadWindows in our applications and it works.  Or, the RadWindow supports a Nested Grid or View that you can have as a record's child; so you can have the master record, click on the arrow on the left and expand the record to view a nested grid of data, or a custom view (via the NestedViewTemplate property).  You can also have the form in a DIV, hide it, then show it via JavaScript too.

Those are two ways.

HTH.